# java query on coding and text encoding

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I have written a program to fetch content from a website to my website using url connection class which gives perfect output on java class. However when I am running the code on jsp special characters as `¾à¤¨`, `à¤®à¥�à¤�à¥‡ à¤‰à¤¨ à¤¬à¤¾à` are displayed in place on Hindi text.

Please help me with this.

Comment: text encoding is difficult

Comment: did you include 

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: Which encodings are you using? Looks like you are using different ones in Java and JSP.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the jsp to use UTF-8 to write HTTP response body using:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

[Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)